# Strange bevaiour of session.add in sqhalchemy (duplicate key value violates unique constraint in session.add))

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.1

I encountered strange behaviour of SQLAlchemy

I tried to add a new object to the DB. This is done in the function `add_tag()`

```py
class News(Base):
    __tablename__ = "news"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    
    def add_tag(self, tag_name, session):
        logging.debug("adding news tags   " + tag_name)
        tag = session.query(Tag).filter_by(name=tag_name).first()
        logging.debug(tag)
        if tag:
            nt = NewsTags()
            nt.tag_id = tag.id
           self.tags.append(nt)
        else:
            new_tag = Tag()
            logging.debug('Creating a new tag:  ' + tag_name)
            new_tag.name = tag_name
            session.add(new_tag)
            session.commit()
            nt = NewsTags()
            nt.tag_id = new_tag.id
            self.tags.append(nt)


class NewsTags(Base):
    __tablename__ = "news_tags"

    news_id = Column(ForeignKey("news.id"), primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(ForeignKey("tag.id"), primary_key=True)
    news = relationship("News", backref="tags")



class Tag(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tag"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30))

    news = relationship(NewsTags, backref="tag", post_update=True)
```

I first check if the object already exists. If it does not, I try to create a new one and add it to the session (add it to the DB).

I already had some objects in the table (create by other means).
See a copy paste of values in table `tag`:

```
id, Name
1   Sports
2   Business
3   Finance
4   World
5   US
6   UK
7   Technology
8   Science
9   Health
10  Video Games
11  IT
12  Startups
13  Europe
14  Apps
15  Space
```

I think I might have added some the data to the DB manually (via SQL insert), but some of it was created through SQLAlchemy.

I came across very strange behavior when trying to add a new object.

First it tried to create an object with id=1 and failed as it was a duplicate. I did not save the stack trace, but I ran it again, it tried to add the object with id=2, here's the stack trace.

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

Full stack trace:

```
DEBUG:root:adding news tags   AI
2022-03-28 06:52:33,188 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT tag.id AS tag_id, tag.name AS tag_name 
FROM tag 
WHERE tag.name = %(name_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT tag.id AS tag_id, tag.name AS tag_name 
FROM tag 
WHERE tag.name = %(name_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
2022-03-28 06:52:33,188 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.005467s ago] {'name_1': 'AI', 'param_1': 1}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[cached since 0.005467s ago] {'name_1': 'AI', 'param_1': 1}
DEBUG:root:None
DEBUG:root:Creating a new tag:  AI
2022-03-28 06:52:33,191 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING tag.id
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING tag.id
2022-03-28 06:52:33,191 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00015s] {'name': 'AI'}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00015s] {'name': 'AI'}
2022-03-28 06:52:33,192 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/assign.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/assign.py", line 46, in main
    parse_feeds(session)
  File "/app/models/VitalNewsFeed.py", line 77, in parse_feeds
    feed.parse_feed(session)
  File "/app/models/VitalNewsFeed.py", line 63, in parse_feed
    new_news = News(entry=e, source=self.source, tags=self.tags, session=session)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 480, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 477, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/app/models/VitalNews.py", line 178, in __init__
    self.add_tag(tag, session)
  File "/app/models/VitalNews.py", line 121, in add_tag
    session.commit()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1431, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3363, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3503, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3463, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 244, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1237, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection._execute_20(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1620, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1487, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1851, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2032, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING tag.id]
[parameters: {'name': 'AI'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

I tried running the script again. Now it tired to create with id=3

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING tag.id]
[parameters: {'name': 'AI'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

id=4

and so on. Every time it failed and I had to run the script again. As if it did not know the last value of id in the table of Tags. After a few fails it created with id=9, which was not a duplicate and the script continued working fine. But the error was strange. Shouldn't it check if primary key is available before creating a new object?
Now the error does not reproduce on dev. But when I pushed my code to prod the same thing happens again.

I am using PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Can you include the type of database used and a minimal table schema?

Comment: @IanWilson added details

Answer (score 0):

This was not SQLAlchemy's fault. It was PostgresSQL and me inserting into the table with a PostgreSQL client Postico without auto-increment which broke the sequence.

Running SQL command of "SELECT setval('tag_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tag), true);" fixed it.